# Jquery collapsible region

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make sections of page collapsible. No plan to use accordion, but simple hide/show to save screen space. See the sample code below. The first link has to click twice to make the section hide, and the second one works fine. Neglect this issue, if you can suggest a better way to do it.. In this example, div1 is in open position and div2 hidden initially.

thanks,
bsr.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<a class="toggle" href="#">Hide</a>
<div class="toggle">
    <p>First div</p>
</div>

<a class="toggle" href="#">Show</a>
<div class="toggle" style="display: none">
    <p>Second div</p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function() {
    $("a.toggle").toggle( 
        function() {
            $(this).text("Hide");
            $(this).next("div.toggle").show();
        },
        function() { 
            $(this).text("Show");
            $(this).next("div.toggle").hide();
        } 
    );  
});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `toggle()` function, as it's not only used to bind toggling events, it also toggles visibility is called without any parameters:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    $("a.toggle").click(function(){
        var $div = $(this).next("div.toggle");
        $div.toggle();
        if($div.is(':visible'))
            $(this).text('Hide');
        else
            $(this).text('Show');
    });
});
```

The problem with your code is that you're showing/hiding the elements regardless of their initial state. No matter what you do, if you bind events using `toggle(func, func)`, the first function will always be called first.

Comment: can i expand this to update the link text (show/hide) as well??

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first one needs to be clicked twice is because it starts with the div showing. When you click on it the first time, because of the nature of the [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), jQuery thinks that you're trying to show it. But it's already showing. So none of the changes take effect.

You can solve this by having everything start out hidden. But if that's not an option, then you'll have to do away with the toggle event listeners and just listen for clicks:

```
$('a.toggle').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() === 'Show') {
        $this.text('Hide').next('div.toggle').show();
    } else {
        $this.text('Show').next('div.toggle').hide();
    }
});
```